# Select a sibling element inside a 'tr' element

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a table like this:

```
<table>
    <th>
        <!--the table heading-->
        <td>id</td>
        <td>type</td>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td>examine</td>
    </th>
    <tr>
        <td>0</td>
        <td>Book</td>
        <td>500</td>
        <button>examine</button> <!-- onclick, get the id value 0 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Clothing</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <button>examine</button> <!-- onclick, get the id value 1 -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Food</td>
        <td>400</td>
        <button>examine</button> <!-- onclick, get the id value 2 -->
    </tr>
    <!--...
    there are 100 rows-->
    <tr>
        <td>99</td>
        <td>Book</td>
        <td>300</td>
        <button>examine</button> <!-- onclick, get the id value 99 -->
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to add an eventListener to the button that when I click the button, it will get the corresponding id value to be passed as an argument in a function. How can I get this done without using JQuery?

Comment: Step 1: fix your HTML. It is invalid to have a `<button>` element as a direct child of a `<tr>` element - put the button inside a `<td>`.

Comment: It's ok man. Actually, I am doing my assignment, and the code above I copy from the course material. No problem with that.

Comment: It's never a good sign when the course material is wrong. Different browsers may handle that invalid HTML differently - you may find the buttons all appear *before* the table element rather than inside the table, and if the browser doesn't put them where you expect then DOM navigation from JS won't work as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Original Answer

The following worked for me:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', () =>
  alert(b.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.nextSibling.innerHTML));
});
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/Luqy0u9m/ for a live demo.

Note that we had to take the second child because the first child of the tr is a text node. You might have to tweak this if the first `td` came directly after the `tr`.

#### Improved Answer

The original answer is bad because it relies on you knowing whether or not there is whitespace between the `<tr>` and its first `<td>`. This is not robust because if you change your HTML the JavaScript breaks.

Instead, look not for the first child node of the `<tr>` but for the first `<td>`. The best way to do this is with the `cells` property of the [HTMLTableRowElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement#Properties) object (your `<tr>`). RobG already gave this answer, so I'll give an alternative (though slower) solution:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(b => {
  b.addEventListener('click', () =>
    alert(b.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('td').innerHTML));
});
```

It's a pretty compact solution, but it does assume that the your button is directly inside a td which is immediately inside a tr whose first td holds the value you want. Still it is way better than the first answer.

Comment: Thanks, it's actually quite easy. I think I need to learn more about the DOM.

Comment: Actually, I have used `currentTarget`, `parentNode` and `firstChild`.

Comment: "*… the first child of the tr is a text node.*" not necessarily, it may be different in different browsers and can depend on white space in the markup. There are much better (i.e. more robust) ways of getting the content.

Comment: Good point, @RobG. No question that the presence or absence of whitespace between the <tr> and the first <td> changes the meaning of firstChild. I thought I made that clear in the answer, but looking back at it it's clear I didn't. You're right though, and the answer was pretty sloppy....having to adjust your code depending on the presence/absence of whitespace in the markup is utter crap. I'll make an edit!

Answer (score 1):

To do this robustly, you first need to go up from the button to the ancestor TR (if there is one), then get the text content of the first cell, e.g.

```js
// Starting at el, get ancestor with tagName
// If no such ancestor, return null
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();
  while (el.parentNode && el.parentNode.tagName) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }
  return null;
}

// Add click listener to all buttons
window.onload = function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('button'),function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click',function() {
      // Get the ancestor row
      var row = upTo(this, 'tr');
      if (row) {
        // If there is a first cell, log it's textContent
        console.log(row.cells[0] && row.cells[0].textContent);
      }
    },false);
  });
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><th>id<th>type<th>Price<th>examine
    <tr><td>0<td>Book<td>500<td><button>examine</button>
    <tr><td>1<td>Clothing<td>30<td><button>examine</button>
</table>
```

This adds the listener to all buttons, you might want to restrict that. Also fixed the HTML to put the buttons in side a cell, and added a first row.